# Keyboard Shortcut to Submit Current Form on Chrome/OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

My favorite shortcut in IE from 10 years ago is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, which submits the form you're currently in.

On Chrome/Windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> has started working recently (though it displays different behavior by submitting "a form" which may or may not be the form you're on). Does anyone know if there is a "submit this form" or "submit a form" keyboard shortcut for Chrome/OS X, and if not, if it is possible to create such a form?

Comment: I don't think there's such a shortcut, but I'd be interested in one for other browsers as well. Normally in OS X ⌤/enter/fn-↩ (not ↩/return) can be used to do something similar, but it doesn't work for most forms in web views... Chrome does support `execute javascript` via AppleScript. Does anyone better at JS know how to submit the current form?

Comment: Lri, you have inspired me to write my own extension to pull this off.

Comment: aaand done. Works on Windows and Mac, alt+shift+s or cmd+shift+s to submit the currently focused form. Will publish it on my site asap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Lri's comment above, I've been inspired to fix this for myself. I've written a Google Chrome extension that will use the alt+shift+s keyboard shortcut on Windows/Linux and cmd+shift+s on Mac to submit the form currently being filled in. Using it now to lazily submit this answer :D

http://neosmart.net/blog/2011/google-chrome-form-quicksubmit/

EDIT

More than five years later, surprisingly no one else has implemented a similar solution so it's (finally) been [published to the Chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-form-quicksubmit/hhhkfkbcnnghmoncpglafjieagfeknhe?hl=en-US&gl=US&authuser=1) and is available for installation/download.

Comment: Nice. I wanted this functionality on a site without the user having to install an extension, so I made a tiny jQuery plugin: https://gist.github.com/3347047

Answer (score 1):

#### Chrome

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell tab 1 of window 1
    execute javascript (do shell script "cat \Library/Documentation/Help/AppleScript.help/Contents/Resources/js/jquery.js")
    execute javascript "$(document.activeElement).closest('form').submit();"
end tell
```

#### Safari

```
tell application "Safari" to tell document 1
    do JavaScript (do shell script "cat /Library/Documentation/Help/AppleScript.help/Contents/Resources/js/jquery.js")
    do JavaScript "$(document.activeElement).closest('form').submit();"
end tell
```

---

Does anyone know any jQuery-less alternative to `$(document.activeElement).closest('form').submit();`?

Comment: You'd have to traverse the tree backwards going to each parent and checking if it's a form.

Comment: I believe this should work `(document.forms[0]).submit()`